# Как передать переменную между активити в ЭТОМ случае?

Tags: android, kotlin

Господа, делаю приложение, в котором нужная часть выглядит следующим образом: пользователь жмякает на кнопочку и вводит дату --> появляется карточка с названием даты в ресайклвью. Пользователь тыкает по карточке, переходит на новую активити и там вновь тыкает на кнопку --> вводит название упражнения и  получает карточку с упражнением.

Сам вопрос: как передать это самое эфемерное значение введеной юзером даты? Нюанс заключается в том, что пользователь может добавить сколько угодно карточек с датами сразу и переменная, которая была мною объявлена внутри класса активи, будет перезаписываться из-за функции, в которой я сохраняю в бд значение введенной даты... А мне бы закидывать переменную с введенной датой в карточку ТАК, чтобы она ОСТАВАЛАСЬ там и не менялась. Таким образом я в дальнейшем смогу между активити передавать мессендж с ключом.

Не могли бы накинуть идей, пожалуйста?

Comment: Не вполне понял что и зачем выделаете, но звучит так, будто вам нужно введённые даты созранять в список и именно этот список в адаптере отображать. Тогда в адаптере будет известно на какую дату нажал юзер и эту дату можно будет далее передавать. Использование одной переменной для списка дат не звучит как хорошая идея.

Comment: Попробовал реализовать так, как вы подсказали. Всё верно;), спасибо! Можете сделать ответ на вопрос, чтобы я вам галочку жмякнул:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Звучит так, будто вам нужно введённые даты сохранять в список и именно этот список в адаптере отображать. Тогда в адаптере будет известно на какую дату нажал юзер и эту дату можно будет далее передавать.

Использование одной переменной для списка дат не звучит как хорошая идея.